# Create duplicate arrays based on a column value

Tags: php

I have the following array, the first item in the array has a quantity of 3 while the rest has a quantity of 1. These numbers are dynamic.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39235995
            [quantity] => 3
            [price] => 2.81
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39236029
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.952
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39236015
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 3.333
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39235997
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.667
        )

)
```

How can I change that to the following output? So the first item that did have a quantity of 3 is now separated out into 3 array items and the quantity set to one for each?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39235995
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.81
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39235995
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.81
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39235995
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.81
        )
        
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39236029
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.952
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39236015
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 3.333
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39235997
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 2.667
        )

)
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve your problem for you. You should post what you've tried and what the output from it is. It should be pretty straight forward though. If you do a foreach loop in which you add the current item to a new array using a for-loop with the quantity as the counter.

Comment: That's a simple task for `foreach`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the original arr and push the contents to a second array. If the quanity > 1 you can create a loop that pushes the item for each quanity. Something like this:

```
    $resultArr = [];
    foreach($arrA as $item){
        for($i = 0; $i < $item['quantity']; $i++){
            // make sure the quantity is now 1 and not the original > 1 value
            $t = $item;
            $t['quantity'] = 1;
            $resultArr[] = $t;
        }
    }
```

Note that the code expects your original array to be called $arrA

Edit: removed the `if/else` as suggested in the comments

Comment: No need for the `if/else`-statement. But honesty, this question shouldn't be answered until the OP shows some effort. Currently, the question is just a "gimme-code" type question.

Comment: hmm wouldnt it be faster if there are a lot of items with quantity 1?

Comment: That's premature micro optimization. If there is a performance diff, it would most likely be negligible. You would also gain from not using a `if/else` check, which you now do in every iteration. And less code usually means easier to read, which in my book is way bigger win than a micro fraction of a second.

Comment: Good question. I assumed because a for loop would be slower than an if statement. But I'm probably wrong :)

Comment: _Small Correction_ Thats an array not an object so `$item->quantity` should be `$item['quantity']`

Comment: _Minor additional fix_ So that you dont get 3 occurances with quantity of 3 in new array